# P(A)=$\frac{1}{3}$,P(B)=$\frac{1}{4}$P(A|B)=$\frac{1}{6}$ then what is P(B|A) equal to?

Tags: probability

P(A)=$\frac{1}{3}$,P(B)=$\frac{1}{4}$P(A|B)=$\frac{1}{6}$ then what is P(B|A) equal to?
**Ans:** $\frac{1}{4}$
this is simple but iam making some mistake
 P(A and B)=P(B)$\times$P(A|B)=$\frac{1}{24}$
P(B|A)=$\frac{P(A\ and\ B)}{P(A)}=\frac{1}{8}$

Update Solution Provided by Author:
P($\frac{B}{A}$)=$\frac{P(A) \times P(B)}{P(A)}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: The answer must be wrong, because your reasoning is just fine.

Comment: they have the solution for it let me update it but that is not what i have learned to calculate P(B|A)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the answer is $P(B)$ tells us that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)\times P(B)$.
Therefore $A$ and $B$ are independent successes.